# What is the long term side effect of lying after eating?

Tags: gerd-acid-reflux, heartburn

I've read online that we shouldn't lie down after eating because it'll contribute to acid reflux. However, I personally never feel the presence of acid reflux if I lie down after eating. What are the other negative effects? Are there any serious long-term potential side effects aside from some possible heartburn (which I personally never experience)?

Comment: lying is general considered bad practice in the western world.  This might be a philosophy question.

Answer (score 3):

Advice against lying down after a meal is usually given to those who already have acid reflux ([WebMD](http://www.webmd.com/heartburn-gerd/heartburn-and-gerd)) and not to everyone.

Reflux comes from excessive relaxation of the lower esophageal sphincter (LES) or diaphragmatic sphincter (the later occurs in hiatal hernia), which results in a free flow of acid into the esophagus when you lie down. If your LES functions properly, you will not likely have acid reflux if you lie down.